# Get all onedrives from c#

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, onedrive-for-business, pnp

I am looking for a c# snippet for getting all OneDrive's. There is a lot of sample for PowerShell, but I am looking for c# snippet that can provide all OneDrives in a tenant.

Comment: what do you mean by "getting all OneDrive's" -- do you want a list users who have a OneDrive?  Do you want a list of url's to each OneDrive?  Do you want a list of files in each user's OneDrive?  Do want to extract metadata or files?

Comment: Just the urls. I will test the answer provided tommorow. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive's are simply specialized/personalized site collections in SharePoint that were created from the **SPSPERS** template.  To find all OneDrives you can use [Brian Jackett's technique for enumerating site collections with CSOM](https://gist.github.com/BrianTJackett/fe20ea446e97dbc849f74d470e7ca65f#file-csom_traverse_all_sites_spo-txt), just add an additional filter to only get sites based on the **SPSPERS** template using the `SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter.Template` property.

Here is a sample (this is nearly identical to Mr. Jackett's, with the addition of the line `sspFilter.Template = "SPSPERS"`) :

```
List <SiteProperties> list = new List <SiteProperties>();

SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable ssp = null;
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter sspFilter = new SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter();
SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myUsernameGoesHere", securePassword);

using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext("myURLGoesHere"))
{
    cc.Credentials = creds;

    String nextIndex = null;
    Tenant tenant = new Tenant(cc);

    //loop through all site collections including personal sites 
    //borrowed this code from after decompiling SPO Management Shell assemblies
    sspFilter.IncludePersonalSite = PersonalSiteFilter.Include;
    sspFilter.IncludeDetail = true;
    sspFilter.Template = "SPSPERS";

    do
    {
        sspFilter.StartIndex = nextIndex;
        ssp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePointByFilters(sspFilter);

        cc.Load(ssp);
        cc.ExecuteQuery();

        list.AddRange(ssp);
        nextIndex = ssp.NextStartIndexFromSharePoint;
    }while(nextIndex != null);

    foreach (SiteProperties sp in list)
    {
        //DO YOUR WORK HERE FOR EACH SITE COLLECTION, such as looping through subwebs
        // OR Logging to a file, or determining user ownership, etc.
        cc.Load(cc.Web, w => w.NoCrawl,
                                    w => w.Webs,
                                    w => w.Url);
        cc.ExecuteQuery();

        //check subweb(s)
        foreach (var subweb in cc.Web.Webs)
        {
            cc.Load(subweb, sw => sw.NoCrawl,
                                        sw => sw.Url);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot will test tommorow.

Comment: Worked, thanks alot!